# implementation of scipy.stats.ncx2

Tags: python, scipy

How can I find details about the implementation of the non-central chi-squared distribution in scipy.stats.ncx2?

The scipy documentation has no information about implementation.

Tracing the source, it seems as if the function is implemented via scipy.special.chndtr. But there is no link to this source from the scipy pages:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.chndtr.html

I feel I'm missing something obvious, but haven't been able to find any info on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/ufuncs.html) as mentioned in [/scipy/special/cdf_wrappers.c](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8dca57d9e08118da7b05232349036bf5ec5774df/scipy/special/cdf_wrappers.c#L163) and [/scipy/special/add_newdocs.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/895a7741b12c2c3f816bfd27e5249468bea64a26/scipy/special/add_newdocs.py#L1086).

The associated Fortran source code is located here:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/special/cdflib,
i.e. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/cdflib/cdfchn.f (as pointed out by @Ras).

Comment: Since it's pretty messy among the files in the pointed folder, for the future reader it may help to leave here the info that main implementation is in this file: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8dba340293fe20e62e173bdf2c10ae208286692f/scipy/special/cdflib/cdfchn.f